# Annotate a receive actor variable in scala-akka framework

Tags: java, scala, akka, newrelic

I am trying add an annotation(newrelic for tracing) to a `persistantActor` `receiveCommand` in scala. But the annotation is not working. This works in other place when annotating a function.

I read that the receive is a partial function not a normal function.

```
class ActorUserMachine extends PersistentActor with ActorLogging {
  @Trace(dispatcher = true)   
  val receiveCommand: Receive = {
     case i:
     case j:
   }
 }
```

Comment: That can be the problem. I suppose you need to use a function that handles your incoming messages and tag it with that annotation. Or take a look to Akka Typed ...

Comment: Using multiple function to annotate as you suggested. Will read about Akka Typed